# QML and PySide6 "TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null"

Tags: python-3.x, qml, pyside6, qt6, qqmlapplicationengine

I am working on an application front-end written in PySide6 that uses Qt Widgets for most of the GUI, but I am trying to add some QML dialogs generated using data sent from a separate back-end.

When trying to launch a QML file, I encounter the following errors:

```
file:///C:/Users/user/dev/qml_dialogs/date_range_dialog/DateRangeDialog.qml:28: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///C:/Users/user/dev/qml_dialogs/date_range_dialog/DateRangeDialog.qml:71: TypeError: Cannot read property 'endDateModel' of null
file:///C:/Users/user/dev/qml_dialogs/date_range_dialog/DateRangeDialog.qml:52: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDateModel' of null
file:///C:/Users/user/dev/qml_dialogs/date_range_dialog/DateRangeDialog.qml:31: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
```

The combo boxes in my QML `ApplicationWindow` only show the first of the string items stored in the `QStringListModel` corresponding to `dateRangeDialog.startDateModel`, which is referenced in QML as `dialog.startDateModel`.

After following some of the documentation from https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/Property.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppstate.html for help with the classes and properties, I created a `DateRangeDialog` class to expose the properties to the QML.

I am trying to use the `DialogManager` to encapsulate the `QQmlApplicationEngine`, set the root context, and load the QML file, since the architecture of the front-end doesn't allow for this to happen in the main function.

Below is a minimal reproducible example using the `DialogManager`, `DateRangeDialog`, and a DateRangeDialog.qml file, all in the same directory, along with the style.qrc file, __init__.py, etc.

Any advice on how to refactor these classes so that the `height`, `width`, and date range properties are accessible from the QML file upon execution?

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from dialog_manager import DialogManager

import style_rc


def main() -> None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialogManager = DialogManager()
    dialogManager.loadDialog(
            name="DateRangeDialog",
            width=800, 
            height=180, 
            startDates=["14/08/23", "15/08/23"], 
            endDates=["15/08/23"]
    )

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**dialog_manager.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QStringListModel
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from date_range_dialog import DateRangeDialog


class DialogManager(QObject):
    _engine: QQmlApplicationEngine

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    def loadDialog(
            self,
            name: str,
            width: float,
            height: float,
            startDates: list[str],
            endDates: list[str]
    ):
        dialog = DateRangeDialog()
        dialog.width = width
        dialog.height = height
        dialog.startDateModel = QStringListModel(startDates)
        dialog.endDateModel = QStringListModel(endDates)

        self._setRootContext(dialog)
        self._loadQmlFile(name)

        root = self._getQQmlEngineRoot()
        try: 
            root.outputDateRange.connect(dialog.outputDateRange)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)

    def _setRootContext(self, dialog: DateRangeDialog):
        self._engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("dialog", dialog)

    def _loadQmlFile(self, qmlName: str) -> None:
        qmlFile = Path(__file__).parent / f"{qmlName}.qml"
        self._engine.load(qmlFile)

    def _getQQmlEngineRoot(self) -> QObject:
        if not self._engine.rootObjects():
            raise AttributeError("Root objects for QQmlApplicationEngine not found")

        root = QObject()
        for rootObject in self._engine.rootObjects():
            if rootObject.inherits("QWindow"): 
                root = rootObject
                break

        return root
```

**date_range_dialog.py**

```
rom PySide6.QtCore import Property, QObject, QStringListModel, Signal


class DateRangeDialog(QObject):
    widthChanged = Signal(float)
    heightChanged = Signal(float)
    startDateModelChanged = Signal(QObject)
    endDateModelChanged = Signal(QObject)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._width = 800 
        self._height = 180
        self._startDateModel = QStringListModel()
        self._endDateModel = QStringListModel()

    def outputDateRange(self, start_date: str, end_date: str) -> None:
        print(f"Start Date: {start_date}, End Date: {end_date}")
    
    @Property(float, notify=widthChanged)
    def width(self) -> float:
        return self._width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, width: float) -> None:
        if self._width != width:
            self._width = width
            self.widthChanged.emit(width)

    @Property(float, notify=heightChanged)
    def height(self) -> float:
        return self._height

    @height.setter
    def height(self, height: float) -> None:
        if self._height != height:
            self._height = height
            self.heightChanged.emit(height)

    @Property(QObject, notify=startDateModelChanged)
    def startDateModel(self):
        return self._startDateModel

    @startDateModel.setter
    def startDateModel(self, startDateModel: QStringListModel) -> None:
        if self._startDateModel != startDateModel:
            self._startDateModel = startDateModel
            self.startDateModelChanged.emit(startDateModel)

    @Property(QObject, notify=endDateModelChanged)
    def endDateModel(self):
        return self._endDateModel

    @endDateModel.setter
    def endDateModel(self, endDateModel: QStringListModel) -> None:
        if self._endDateModel != endDateModel:
            self._endDateModel = endDateModel
            self.endDateModelChanged.emit(endDateModel)
```

**DateRangeDialog.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    signal buttonClicked(string buttonText);
    signal outputDateRange(string startDate, string endDate);

    Component.onCompleted: { 
        console.log("Initialised DateRangeDialog")
        root.buttonClicked.connect(closeDialog); 
    }
    function closeDialog(buttonText) {
        console.log(buttonText + " clicked");

        if (buttonText === "OK") {
            var startDate = startDateComboBox.currentText;
            var endDate = endDateComboBox.currentText;
            root.outputDateRange(startDate, endDate);
        }

        close();
    }

    visible: true
    width: dialog.width
    minimumWidth: width
    maximumWidth: width
    height: dialog.height
    minimumHeight: height
    maximumHeight: height
    flags: Qt.Dialog
    title: qsTr("Enter Report Range")

    Label {
        id: startDateLabel

        anchors.right: startDateComboBox.left
        anchors.rightMargin: parent.width / 20
        anchors.verticalCenter: startDateComboBox.verticalCenter
        text: qsTr("Start Date: ")
    }
    ComboBox {
        id: startDateComboBox

        anchors.right: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.rightMargin: parent.width / 40
        anchors.bottom: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.bottomMargin: parent.height / 8
        model: dialog.startDateModel
        textRole: "display"
    }

    Label {
        id: endDateLabel

        anchors.left: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.leftMargin: parent.width / 40
        anchors.verticalCenter: endDateComboBox.verticalCenter
        text: qsTr("End Date: ")
    }
    ComboBox {
        id: endDateComboBox

        anchors.left: endDateLabel.right
        anchors.leftMargin: parent.width / 20
        anchors.bottom: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.bottomMargin: parent.height / 8
        model: dialog.endDateModel
        textRole: "display"
    }

    Button {
        id: okButton

        onClicked: root.buttonClicked(text);

        anchors.right: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.rightMargin: parent.width / 40
        anchors.top: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.topMargin: parent.height / 6
        text: qsTr("OK")
    }

    Button {
        id: cancelButton

        onClicked: root.buttonClicked(text);

        anchors.left: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.leftMargin: parent.width / 40
        anchors.top: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.topMargin: parent.height / 6
        text: qsTr("Cancel")
    }
}
```

Comment: The `dialog` instance is probably garbage collected: as the [`setContextProperty()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) documentation says, "`QQmlContext` does **not** take ownership of *value*." Try to change to `self.dialog = ...`

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! Making the `dialog` instance an attribute of `DialogManager` prevented it from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment from [@musicamente](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) for correct answer. Assigning the `dialog` instance as an attribute of `DialogManager` prevented the `dialog` instance from being garbage collected, and it remains as an accessible component in the QML.

See corrected `DialogManager` class below.

**dialog_manager.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QStringListModel
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from date_range_dialog import DateRangeDialog


class DialogManager(QObject):
    _engine: QQmlApplicationEngine
    _dialog: DateRangeDialog

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    def loadDialog(
            self,
            name: str,
            width: float,
            height: float,
            title: str,
            startDates: list[str],
            endDates: list[str]
    ):
        self.dialog = DateRangeDialog()
        self.dialog.width = width
        self.dialog.height = height
        self.dialog.title = title
        self.dialog.startDateModel = QStringListModel(startDates)
        self.dialog.endDateModel = QStringListModel(endDates)

        self._setRootContext(self.dialog)
        self._loadQmlFile(name)

        root = self._getQQmlEngineRoot()
        try: 
            root.outputDateRange.connect(self.dialog.outputDateRange)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print(e)

    def _setRootContext(self, dialog: DateRangeDialog):
        self._engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("dialog", dialog)

    def _loadQmlFile(self, qmlName: str) -> None:
        qmlFile = Path(__file__).parent / f"{qmlName}.qml"
        self._engine.load(qmlFile)

    def _getQQmlEngineRoot(self) -> QObject:
        if not self._engine.rootObjects():
            raise AttributeError("Root objects for QQmlApplicationEngine not found")

        root = QObject()
        for rootObject in self._engine.rootObjects():
            if rootObject.inherits("QWindow"): 
                root = rootObject
                break

        return root
```